# Rake aborted PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: database "vagrant" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, vagrant, vagrantfile

How to run `rake db:migrate` using `postgres` user for database `my_db`. The role `postgres` and `my_db` database are created but when try to run migrate command , it throws error. Please let me know if I am missing any step.I don't want to use `vagrant` user and `vagrant database`

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ vagrant ssh
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ psql -h localhost -d my_db -U postgres
my_db=#\q
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ rake db:migrate
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "vagrant" does not exist
```

```
                         List of roles
```

```
-----------+------------------------------------------------+----------
postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

```
                    List of databases
```

```
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------
 my_db      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

Comment: In what environment is the application running? You originally asked about `test`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a database configuration through `config/database.yml`. If you are going to use PG for both environments (`development` and `test`), it can look like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db
  username: postgres
  password: PASSWORD

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_test
  username: postgres
  password: PASSWORD
```

Documentation: [Configuring a postgresql database](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: Thanks @michael - I changed the name of database in question to avoid confusion. 


```vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ cat /home/vagrant/.pgpass 
    localhost:5432:test:postgres:xyz```

Comment: @sandy So, just add `test` as `database`, `postgres` as `username` and `xyz` as `password` to the yml file.

Comment: @sandy Or you can use `my_db` as `database` if it exists on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. I have defined database name , user, password in `/home/vagrant/.pgpass ` and it works for another setup. The .yml file does not have any info in that setup. I need to keep this new setup same to keep consistency.